# How to get position of my letter from string using PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

The letter is `m` and my string is `asdvbgmfger`.

When I run the code I want to get `m position is 6`. The position start at `0`.

**I use this code but didn't work:**

```
<?php
$str = "asdvbgmfger";

if (preg_match_all('/\p{L}/u', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) > 0) {
    $lastMatch = "m";
    echo 'm position is '.$lastMatch[1];
} else {
    echo 'no letters found';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not use strpos instead of regex?

Comment: Did you write this code? There are lot of things wrong with this

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this way: https://3v4l.org/l0p5a

```
<?php
$str = "asdvbgmfger";
$strPosition = strpos($str, 'm');

if ($strPosition !== false) {
    echo 'm position is ' . $strPosition;
} else {
    echo 'no letters found';
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: You should change your code to `if ($strPosition) !== false`, because if the position is 0, the condition will fail.